# How to Map fields of the response object to new arrays in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7, subscribe

I want to map the response from service to different arrays. My response is of type

```
{
  "success": true,
  "dataPoints": [{
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2817,
    "startTime": "00:00:00",
    "endTime": "00:19:59.999"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2814,
    "startTime": "00:59:59.997",
    "endTime": "01:19:59.996"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2816,
    "startTime": "00:39:59.998",
    "endTime": "00:59:59.997"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2825,
    "startTime": "02:19:59.993",
    "endTime": "02:39:59.992"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2828,
    "startTime": "02:39:59.992",
    "endTime": "02:59:59.991"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2832,
    "startTime": "02:59:59.991",
    "endTime": "03:19:59.99"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2841,
    "startTime": "03:39:59.989",
    "endTime": "03:59:59.988"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2816,
    "startTime": "01:39:59.995",
    "endTime": "01:59:59.994"
  }, {
    "count_id": 5,
    "avg_temperature": 2668,
    "startTime": "04:19:59.987",
    "endTime": "04:39:59.986"
  }, {
    "count_id": 3,
    "avg_temperature": 2711,
    "startTime": "05:19:59.984",
    "endTime": "05:39:59.983"
  }]
```

I want to create an array of startTime , endTime, avg_temperature. I have read that it can be done by creating an interface of response type and map the fields. but i am not sure how to map. can someone help?

```
getHistoryData() {
  this.historyDataService.getHistoryData(this.payload)
    .subscribe(data => {this.responeData = data as IResponseData[];
      console.log(this.responeData);
  });
```

Comment: Do you want 3 arrays one for `startTime` , `endTime` and `avg_temperature` each or 1 array for all 3 values?

Comment: 3 seperate arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any difficult.

if you have your supposed data, it must works as you expected.

```
    const response = {
        "success": true,
        "dataPoints": [{
            "count_id": 4,
            "avg_temperature": 2817,
            "startTime": "00:00:00",
            "endTime": "00:19:59.999"
        }, {
            "count_id": 4,
            "avg_temperature": 2814,
            "startTime": "00:59:59.997",
            "endTime": "01:19:59.996"
        }, {
            "count_id": 4,
            "avg_temperature": 2816,
            "startTime": "00:39:59.998",
            "endTime": "00:59:59.997"
        }, {
            "count_id": 4,
            "avg_temperature": 2825,
            "startTime": "02:19:59.993",
            "endTime": "02:39:59.992"
        }, {
            "count_id": 4,
            "avg_temperature": 2828,
            "startTime": "02:39:59.992",
            "endTime": "02:59:59.991"
        }, {
            "count_id": 4,
            "avg_temperature": 2832,
            "startTime": "02:59:59.991",
            "endTime": "03:19:59.99"
        }, {
            "count_id": 4,
            "avg_temperature": 2841,
            "startTime": "03:39:59.989",
            "endTime": "03:59:59.988"
        }, {
            "count_id": 4,
            "avg_temperature": 2816,
            "startTime": "01:39:59.995",
            "endTime": "01:59:59.994"
        }, {
            "count_id": 5,
            "avg_temperature": 2668,
            "startTime": "04:19:59.987",
            "endTime": "04:39:59.986"
        }, {
            "count_id": 3,
            "avg_temperature": 2711,
            "startTime": "05:19:59.984",
            "endTime": "05:39:59.983"
        }]
    };


startTime = [];
avg_temperature = [];
endTime = [];

getHistoryData() {
        this.startTime = [];
        this.avg_temperature = [];
        this.endTime = [];
        this.historyDataService
                .getHistoryData(this.payload)
                .subscribe(
                    (data: any) => 
                {
                    const responeData: any = data.dataPoints;
                    if(responeData == null){
                        return; // you don't have the expected data
                    }
                    startTime = responeData.map(e => e.startTime);
                    endTime = responeData.map(e => e.endTime);
                    avg_temperature = responeData.map(e => e.avg_temperature);
                }
        );
```

Comment: Ah!!! this is the solution. Thank you. I just had to add this.  to startTime, endTime and avg_temoperature in the last three lines. Can you tell why did u have to initialize startTime , endTime and avg_temoperature two times, once outside the function and  once inside the function

Comment: @Chinni I initialized only to be sure, there is no special reason. you can only declare outside and manage into your function.

Comment: I have tried with initiliazing  only outside and its working

Answer (score 0):

Declare 3 arrays to hold startime,endtime and avg_temperature;

```
startTime = [];
endTime = [];
avg_temperature = [];
getHistoryData() {
    this.historyDataService.getHistoryData(this.payload)
        .subscribe(data => {
        this.responeData = data.dataPoints as IResponseData[];
        this.responseData.forEach(x =>{
            this.startTime.push(x.startTime),
            this.endTime.push(x.endtime),
            this.avg_temperature.push(x.avg_temperature)}
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: ` x ` in `x.endtime` and `x.avg_temperature` throws an error - `can not find x in .ts (2304)`

Comment: There should be an semi colon after the first startTime.Push(...).I updated my response

Comment: No, changing to semi-colon does not help. still the same error with an additional at the first semi-colon after startTime.push(...)

Comment: @Ashok your missing the `{ }` brackets in your `forEach` callback.

Comment: Ah that’s what it is ..Thanks !

Comment: Thanks ! No error during compile time but when i make call the function, i get an error `core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: _this.responeData.forEach is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next (milo-parameters.component.ts:99)
    at `

Comment: It means that the response is not an array.can you post how the response looks like?

Comment: In the question descripton I have added how the response object looks like, you can use that for reference

Comment: That’s the problem ..we were iterating responsedate ,instead we should be iterating reaponsedata.datapoints

Comment: You should declare the three arrays inside of `getHistoryData`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for

```
getHistoryData() {
    this.historyDataService.getHistoryData(this.payload).subscribe(response => {
        const {dataPoints} = response;
        const result = {
            startTimes: dataPoints.map(p => p.startTime),
            endTimes: dataPoints.map(p => p.endTime),
            avgTemperatures: dataPoints.map(p => p.avg_temperature)
        };
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: shows an error `Property 'dataPoints' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)` in line number 3

Comment: @Chinni But in your question you showed that the `response` does have that property? Maybe you need to fix the type of `historyDataService.getHistoryData()`.

Comment: I didn't say you need to change the response, I said you need to change your type annotations so that TypeScript accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```js
const data = {
  "success": true,
  "dataPoints": [{
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2817,
    "startTime": "00:00:00",
    "endTime": "00:19:59.999"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2814,
    "startTime": "00:59:59.997",
    "endTime": "01:19:59.996"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2816,
    "startTime": "00:39:59.998",
    "endTime": "00:59:59.997"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2825,
    "startTime": "02:19:59.993",
    "endTime": "02:39:59.992"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2828,
    "startTime": "02:39:59.992",
    "endTime": "02:59:59.991"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2832,
    "startTime": "02:59:59.991",
    "endTime": "03:19:59.99"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2841,
    "startTime": "03:39:59.989",
    "endTime": "03:59:59.988"
  }, {
    "count_id": 4,
    "avg_temperature": 2816,
    "startTime": "01:39:59.995",
    "endTime": "01:59:59.994"
  }, {
    "count_id": 5,
    "avg_temperature": 2668,
    "startTime": "04:19:59.987",
    "endTime": "04:39:59.986"
  }, {
    "count_id": 3,
    "avg_temperature": 2711,
    "startTime": "05:19:59.984",
    "endTime": "05:39:59.983"
  }]
};

const temp = data.dataPoints.map(obj => obj.avg_temperature);
const startTime = data.dataPoints.map(obj => obj.startTime);
const endTime = data.dataPoints.map(obj => obj.endTime);

console.log(temp);
console.log(startTime);
console.log(endTime);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can reduce the response to three separate arrays like this really simple:

```
// Helper function to map the object response to three arrays
mapResponse(response): DataVM {
   return reponse && response.dataPoints ? response.dataPoints.reduce((total, curr) => {
      return {
         ...total,
         avgTemp: [...total.avgTemp, curr.avg_temperature],
         endTime: [...total.startTime, curr.startTime],
         startTime: [...total.endTime, curr.endTime]
      }
    }, {avgTemp: [], startTime: [], endTime: []}) : null;
}
```

```
// Map the response in pipe (Rx 5.5+) or .map (older RxJS versions)
getHistoryData() {
  this.historyDataService.getHistoryData(this.payload)
      .pipe(map(this.mapResponse))
      .subscribe(data => {
           console.log(data);
  });
```

You can also create an interface to reflect your view model like:

```
export interface DataVM{
   avgTemp: number[],
   endTime: string[],
   startTime: string[]
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Error - `core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined`

Comment: Add a console.log (or debug) to the first line in the `mapResponse` function. What is the point of downvoting? The method is working just fine, tested by me :). `reduce of undefined` means there is no `dataPoints` array in the response. I will edit the answer to check that.

Comment: Most probably your API doesn't return any data, try to fix the `getHistoryData` method. Does it print `null` with the validation added?

Comment: I haven't downvoted,its someone else.. anyways I'll check what you have mentioned.